# Laravel 5.2.45 : Undefined variable: states

Tags: laravel

I am trying to output states from my database when I do so it shows :

> Undefined variable: states (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Prayas1\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

This is my welcome blade:

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => 'state']) !!}
    <select>
        @foreach($states as $state)
            <option value="{{$state->state_name}}" data-id="{{$state->state_id}}">{{$state->state_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

And I have defined the "states" variable in the StateController:

```
class StateController extends Controller
{
public function getState()
{
    $states=DB::table('tbl_state')->get();
    return View('welcome')->with($states);
}
}
```

I just don't understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the -1 in my question. I searched for it, tested it several times, when it didn't work, then only asked the question here. Even after the solution, I don't know the difference between the two: with($states) and with('states', $states). Why was my question judged with a negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
return View('welcome')->with('states', $states);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, It did work. But, please can you tell me why it wasn't working on first place?...

Comment: First place you need to declare variable name which is accessible from the view and then value.

Answer (score 1):

```
return view(welcome , compact('state'));
```

Would be the right way.